# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could someone help me through this problem?
Prove that $$\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=0$$

Comment: I think you have a typo: it should rather be $n\to \infty$ and not $x\to \infty$, otherwise the result doesn't hold.

Comment: do you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}$?

Comment: I presume you mean $n \rightarrow \infty$. First try showing $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 
$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ 
and 
$$0\leq \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$
 then because 
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=0$$

we have $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=0$.

Comment: Once you have $1\over n(n + 1)$, the problem has fallen; no need to drag $1\over n^2$ into it. IMHO, of course.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* convert that difference into a single fraction.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** First convince yourself that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and subsequently that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=0$.

Comment: Just as the OP, you're using $x$ and $n$ simultaneously when you should either choose $n$ or $x$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Silly mistake, fixed now